# The option [methodName] is not supported

Tags: node.js, prototype

I'm trying to extend the `Object` class in my js app.

Here's the method:

```
Object.prototype.safeGet = function(props, defaultValue) {
  console.log(this, props, defaultValue);
  if (typeof props === 'string') {
    props = props.split('.');
  }
  if (this === undefined || this === null) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  if (props.length === 0) {
    return this;
  }
  return this.safeGet(props.slice(1), defaultValue);
};
```

When I load this, I get:

```
the options [safeGet] is not supported
```

And then the method seems to be called (while I don't anywhere in my code), with the following arguments (from the `console.log`):

```
SchemaString {
  enumValues: [],
  regExp: null,
  path: 'source',
  instance: 'String',
  validators: 
   [ { validator: [Function],
       message: 'Path `{PATH}` is required.',
       type: 'required' } ],
  setters: [],
  getters: [],
  options: 
   { type: [Function: String],
     index: true,
     required: true,
     safeGet: [Function],
     runSettersOnQuery: undefined },
  _index: true,
  isRequired: true,
  requiredValidator: [Function],
  originalRequiredValue: true } [Function] undefined
```

Using NodeJS

```
$ node --version
v4.8.3
```

Any idea what's going on? Changing the name won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`, which will be "visible" during object iteration, which Mongoose seems to be doing (and it's confusing it for a function that it needs to call).

Instead, you want to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to add a property that isn't enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'safeGet', {
  value : function(props, defaultValue) {
    console.log(this, props, defaultValue);
    if (typeof props === 'string') {
      props = props.split('.');
    }
    if (this === undefined || this === null) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    if (props.length === 0) {
      return this;
    }
    return this.safeGet(props.slice(1), defaultValue);
  }
});
```

However, if you use this method mainly to deal with Mongoose objects/documents, you should probably consider creating a [plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) instead.